# How to use multi-languages for iPhone application using NSBUNDLE?

Tags: ios, localization

How to use multi languages for iPhone application?. Currently I used five languages. How to use it in iPhone development using nsbundle?

Comment: Try [this](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/ios-sdk-localization-with-nslocalizedstring--mobile-11603)

Answer (score 0):

Their is one easiest way to develop multi language app by using string file. only you need to make different string file for each languages and then use NSLocalizedString to use current language. For Ex:

UIlabel *label;
label.text= NSLocalizedString(@"Key", nil);

and in Localizable.strings (english) string file it will be defined as

"Key"="English Name";

and in Localizable.strings (german) string file it will be defined as

"Key"="german Name";

It will automatically set the value of current language on uilabel from device.

And you can localize the xib directly , it will create different xib for each language and set the text accordingly.